# HTML and CSS / School project

Tags: html, css

There is line of code that's called "vertikalni" and "baner". I want to put that part under header and to be horizontal. That part should have same size as header.

Vertical one don't even need to be where it is now, just need to swap their positions. I am having difficulties when I swap their places in html and CSS, it always dissolve my whole layout.

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  width: 692px;
  /*750-2x5-2x24=692*/
  padding: 24px;
}

header {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 46px;
  /*80-2x2-2x15=46*/
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  /*ili u delu ispod margin-top*/
}

#slika {
  width: 204px;
  /*238-2x15-2x2=204*/
  height: 366px;
  /*400-2x15-2x2=366*/
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 24px;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
}

#pesma {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 254px;
  /*306-2x2-2x24=254*/
  height: 348px;
  /*400-2x2-2x24=348*/
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 24px;
  float: left;
}

#vertikalni {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  /*ili u divu pesma margin-right*/
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  float: left;
}

footer {
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 18px;
  /*70-2x2-2x24=18*/
  padding: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  clear: left;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0px;
}

.baner {
  width: 98px;
  /*100-2x1=98*/
  height: 98px;
  /*100-2x1=98*/
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  background-color: #999;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 198px;
  /*202-2x2=198*/
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <p>Naši najveći pesnici u istoriji književnosti</p>
  </header>
  <div id="pesma">
    <h1>Čarobna vrata</h1>
    <p>Na svetu zemlja jedna postoji,<br> puna je svakoga blaga,<br> i sve što ima — podeli svima<br> u tome joj je snaga.</p>
    <p>Hoćeš li kuće, i kuća ima,<br> samo uzmi i gradi,<br> mostove hoćeš, pozovi ljude,<br> džinovski most sagradi.</p>
    <p>Hoćeš li pesme, u njoj se ore,<br> pevaju milioni,<br> svako te tamo na rad zove,<br> a niko te ne goni.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="vertikalni">
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="slika">
    <img src="slike/mira.jpg" alt="Portret">
    <p><b>Mira Alečković</b></p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Ovo je zadatak čiji je sadržaj preuzet sa <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Vikipedije.</a></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: What have you tried? We're not a free coding service. Your snippet should show some effort made to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

This problem will be solved with this step-by-step solution:

1. Move the `#vertikalni` div under the `header` tag to place it exactly under the header.
2. Change the width of `#silka` and `#pesma` div to `42%` for matching the width of the header above it.
3. Add `margin-bottom: 24px` in `#silka` div for giving a space to `footer` tag below.
4. Remove `width: 100px; margin-left: 24px;` for matching the width of the header.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  width: 692px;
  /*750-2x5-2x24=692*/
  padding: 24px;
}

header {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 46px;
  /*80-2x2-2x15=46*/
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  /*ili u delu ispod margin-top*/
}

#slika {
  width: 42%; /* Step 2 */
  /*238-2x15-2x2=204*/
  height: 366px;
  /*400-2x15-2x2=366*/
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 24px;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 24px; /* Step 3 */
}

#pesma {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 42%; /* Step 2 */
  /*306-2x2-2x24=254*/
  height: 348px;
  /*400-2x2-2x24=348*/
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 24px;
  float: left;
}

#vertikalni {
  /* Step 4 */
  /*ili u divu pesma margin-right*/
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  float: left;
}

footer {
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 18px;
  /*70-2x2-2x24=18*/
  padding: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  clear: left;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0px;
}

.baner {
  width: 97px; /* Step 5 */
  /*100-2x1=98*/
  height: 98px;
  /*100-2x1=98*/
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  background-color: #999;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 198px;
  /*202-2x2=198*/
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <p>Naši najveći pesnici u istoriji književnosti</p>
  </header>
  <!-- Step 1 -->
  <div id="vertikalni">
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
    <div class="baner"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="pesma">
    <h1>Čarobna vrata</h1>
    <p>Na svetu zemlja jedna postoji,<br> puna je svakoga blaga,<br> i sve što ima — podeli svima<br> u tome joj je snaga.</p>
    <p>Hoćeš li kuće, i kuća ima,<br> samo uzmi i gradi,<br> mostove hoćeš, pozovi ljude,<br> džinovski most sagradi.</p>
    <p>Hoćeš li pesme, u njoj se ore,<br> pevaju milioni,<br> svako te tamo na rad zove,<br> a niko te ne goni.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="slika">
    <img src="slike/mira.jpg" alt="Portret">
    <p><b>Mira Alečković</b></p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Ovo je zadatak čiji je sadržaj preuzet sa <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Vikipedije.</a></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Don't assume everyone understands what you did by posting a code dump.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the placing the "vertikalni" div underneath your header in your html file. Because that is where you want it to show up. You have your header in your wrapper so if you put the width of #vertikalni to 100% you will see that the baner divs will be horizontal. Because the baner divs has restricted width to 98px so it won't be as long as the header. We got a width of 100% devided by 4 divs is a width of 25%. So if you set the width to 25% it will fit, also remove the margin-left or else it will flow over.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).